# Subprocess, Multiprocessing, thread. Зависание программы. Python

Tags: python

Написал три отдельных метода для расчета числа ПИ с выводом промежуточных значений. Но почему, то при запуске всех трех методов компьютер зависает. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Может я не правильно высвобождаю ресурсы?
Вот код основного файла.

```
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import random, threading, subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value, Array,Manager

class PI:       
    def __init__(self):
        self.count=0
        self.allcount=0
        self.pointNumber = 10000000
        self.aPiarr = []
        self.timearr= []
        self.radius=1
        self.threadCount = 4
        self.aPi=0

    def LeibnicPI(self):
        i=0
        self.aPi=0
        while i<self.pointNumber: 
            self.aPi += pow(-1, i) / (2 * i + 1)
            i+=1
        self.aPi = 4 * self.aPi
        print("Пи Лейбница:",self.aPi)
        print("----------------------------------------------")

    def Thred(self):
        self.count=0   
        self.allcount=0
        self.aPiarr = []
        self.timearr= []
        shag = self.pointNumber // self.threadCount
        lock = threading.Lock()
        i=0
        p = [0] * self.threadCount
        startTime = datetime.now()
        while i < self.threadCount: 
            if i + 1 != self.threadCount:
                p[i] = threading.Thread(target=self.MonteCarloMethod, args=(shag*i, shag*(i+1), startTime, lock))
                p[i].start() 
            else:
                p[i] = threading.Thread(target= self.MonteCarloMethod, args=(shag*i, self.pointNumber, startTime, lock))
                p[i].start() 
            i+=1
        for x in p[:]:
            x.join()
        endTime = datetime.now()        
        print("Pi Thread: ", 4.0 * (self.count / self.pointNumber))
        print("Точность расчета:", abs(self.aPi - 4.0 * (self.count / self.pointNumber)))
        print("Время выполнения Thread: ", endTime - startTime)
        print("Промежуточное время:")
        for time in self.timearr: 
            print(str(time))                
        print("Массив отклонений:", self.aPiarr)
        print("----------------------------------------------")

    def MonteCarloMethod(self, start, end, startTime, lock):
        while start < end:    
            if (self.IsCircle()):
                lock.acquire()
                self.count+=1
                lock.release()
            #Промежуточный вывод значений
            lock.acquire() 
            self.allcount+=1
            lock.release()
            if (self.allcount % 1000000 == 0):
                self.aPiarr.append(abs(self.aPi - 4 * (self.count / self.allcount)))
                self.timearr.append(datetime.now() - startTime)
            start+=1

    def Multiproc(self):        
        with Manager() as manager:
            shag = self.pointNumber // self.threadCount       
            y=0 
            lock = Lock()
            d = Value('d', 0.0)
            i = Value('d', 0.0)
            aPiarr = manager.list()
            timearr = manager.list()
            p = [0] * self.threadCount
            startTime = datetime.now()
            procs = []
            while y < self.threadCount: 
                if y + 1 != self.threadCount:
                    proc = Process(target=self.forMultiproc, args=(d, aPiarr, timearr, lock, shag*y, shag*(y+1), startTime, self.aPi,i))
                    procs.append(proc)
                    proc.start()
                else:
                    proc = Process(target=self.forMultiproc, args=(d,aPiarr, timearr, lock,shag*y, self.pointNumber, startTime, self.aPi,i))
                    procs.append(proc)
                    proc.start()
                y+=1
            for proc in procs:
                    proc.join()
            endTime = datetime.now()                      
            print("Pi Multiproc:",4.0 * (d.value / self.pointNumber))
            print("Точность расчета:", abs(self.aPi-4.0 * (d.value / self.pointNumber)))
            print("Время выполнения Multiproc: ", endTime - startTime)
            #Промежуточный вывод значений
            print("Промежуточное время:")
            for time in timearr: 
                print(str(time))                
            print("Массив отклонений:", aPiarr)
            print("----------------------------------------------")

    def forMultiproc(self, d, aPiarr, timearr, lock, start, end, startTime, aPi,i):
        while start < end:            
            if (self.IsCircle()):
                lock.acquire()
                d.value+=1
                lock.release()
            lock.acquire()
            i.value+=1
            lock.release()
            if (i.value%1000000 == 0):
                aPiarr.append(abs(aPi-4*(d.value/i.value)))
                timearr.append(datetime.now()-startTime)
            start+=1

    def IsCircle(self):           
            x = random.random()
            y = random.random()           
            return ((x * x + y * y) <= self.radius * self.radius)

    def subproc(self):
        count=0
        aPiarr = []
        timearr = []
        startTime = datetime.now()
        i=1
        try:
            while i<11:
                processes = [Popen('python sub.py',stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,shell=True) for i in range(4)]
                for p in processes[:]:
                    p.stdin.write(str(250000).encode('UTF-8'))
                    p.stdin.close()            
                while processes:
                    for p in processes[:]:
                        if p.poll() is not None:
                            con = p.stdout.read().decode('UTF-8')
                            count+=float(con[:-2])
                            p.stdout.close()
                            processes.remove(p)
                print(count)
                timearr.append(datetime.now()-startTime)
                aPiarr.append(abs(self.aPi-4*(count/(i*1000000))))
                i+=1
        except subprocess.SubprocessError as e:
            print(e)
        endTime = datetime.now()
        print("Pi Subprocess: ", 4.0 * (count/((i-1)*1000000)))
        print("Точность расчета: ", abs(self.aPi - 4.0 * (count/((i-1)*1000000))))
        print("Время выполнения Subprocess: ", endTime - startTime)
        print("Промежуточное время: ")
        for time1 in timearr: 
            print(str(time1))
        print("Массив отклонений:", aPiarr)

    def Single(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.allcount = 0
        self.aPiarr = []
        self.timearr= []
        startTime = datetime.now()
        for i in range(self.pointNumber):
            if (self.IsCircle()):
                self.count+=1           
            self.allcount+=1
            if (self.allcount % 1000000 == 0):
                self.aPiarr.append(abs(self.aPi - 4 * (self.count / self.allcount)))
                self.timearr.append(datetime.now() - startTime)
        endTime = datetime.now() 
        print("Pi Single: ", 4.0 * (self.count / self.pointNumber))
        print("Точность расчета: ", abs(self.aPi - 4.0 * (self.count / self.pointNumber)))
        print("Время выполнения Single: ", endTime - startTime)
        print("Промежуточное время: ")
        for time in self.timearr: 
            print(str(time))                
        print("Массив отклонений: ", self.aPiarr)
        print("----------------------------------------------")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clas= PI()
    clas.LeibnicPI()
    clas.Thred()  
    clas.Multiproc()
    clas.subproc() 
    clas.Single()
```

Вот код дочернего файла для `Subprocess` .

```
import sys
import random

def IsCircle():           
    x = random.random()
    #print(x)
    y = random.random()           
    return ((x * x + y * y) <= 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = sys.stdin.read()
    count=0
    for i in range(int(a)):    
        if (IsCircle()):
            count+=1
    print(count)
```

Comment: Сделайте форматирование своему коду, в таком виде его сложно просматривать

Comment: Могли бы Вы добавить что Ваш код выводит до зависания.
И ещё, могли бы Вы подсказать назначение функции **isCircle**. Судя по названию, ей нужно передавать x и y через аргументы...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Про документировал. Получается зависает он на multiprocessing если запускать остальные методы внизу. Как я понял он вызывает все функции в классе из за этого if __name__ == '__main__':  по ходу в этом причина зависания. Но если эту строку убрать, то он ничего не выполняет вообще. Не знаю как исправить. Кстати в ответе вы исправили вторую ошибку, которую я не заметил и добавил в subprocess вашу строку "python sub.py". =)

Comment: @AndrioSkur Про документировал, как вы просили, по быстрому код. По ходу ошибка из за if name == 'main': (он вызывает все функции), но если ее убрать код дальше для multiprocessing перестает работать, не знаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы он начал работать как надо.

Comment: Как я написал в ответе, после добавления `python` в вызове `sub.py` код не зависает и отрабатывает до завершения. Если он по-прежнему зависает у Вас, скажите на каком моменте он зависает - что код выводит до того, как зависнуть. Я не имел в виду документированность кода, а конкретно содержимое Вашей консоли после запуска кода.

Comment: И куда это у Вас блок уехал? В оригинальном вопросе он был за пределами класса, а сейчас Вы его внесли под класс.
`    clas= PI()`
`    clas.LeibnicPI()`
`    clas.Thred()`
`    clas.Multiproc()`
`    clas.subproc()`

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Получается если запустить внизу все функции, то у меня он выведет вначале LeibnicPI(), Thred(), а после зависнет. У моего друга, он когда запустил то у него все работало. Но функции Thred(), LeibnicPI(), subproc() выводятся несколько раз. А когда он запустил отладчик, то увидел что строка if __name__ == '__main__': в функции Multiproc() вызывает все остальные методы класса. А извините, это случайно щас исправлю.

Comment: У Вас там много чего поехало по сравнению с начальным вариантом. Но идея становится понятной. Дерзайте, а мне на работу пора... Вечерком посмотрю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под Windows тестируете? Замените `sub.py` на `python sub.py` в строке

`processes = [Popen('sub.py',stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,shell=True) for i in range(4)]`

После этого код отрабатывает. Хотя Ваша функция isCircle мне так и не понятна. :)

```
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.1458
Точность расчета: 0.004217346410280154
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:03.600956
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.042999
0:00:00.535006
0:00:00.976997
0:00:01.365039
0:00:01.764000
0:00:02.208986
0:00:02.660979
0:00:03.126972
0:00:03.456967
0:00:03.600956
Массив отклонений: [0.012382653589719794, 0.024182653589719827, 0.0077159869230531974, 0.006382653589719567, 0.0024626535897196433, 0.00311598692305326, 0.0027030606959943526, 0.005117346410280277, 0.004728457521391505, 0.004217346410280154]
----------------------------------------------
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.14692
Точность расчета: 0.005337346410280386
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:03.696954
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.350920
0:00:00.749934
0:00:01.150910
0:00:01.485909
0:00:01.865901
0:00:02.256898
0:00:02.642899
0:00:03.026890
0:00:03.431925
0:00:03.695955
Массив отклонений: [0.0019826535897196074, 0.006817346410280312, 0.002817346410280308, 0.008817346410280091, 0.009297346410280127, 0.006550679743613674, 0.006131632124565911, 0.004417346410280132, 0.005350679743613362, 0.005337346410280386]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Subprocess: 2.853418181818182
Точность расчета: 0.2881644717715379
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:02.461898
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.245925
0:00:00.500924
0:00:00.746914
0:00:00.981916
0:00:01.227911
0:00:01.472912
0:00:01.716905
0:00:01.964902
0:00:02.213901
0:00:02.461898
Массив отклонений: [0.008417346410280135, 0.0005826535897197616, 0.006150679743613718, 0.008717346410280324, 0.0008973464102801643, 0.002715986923053304, 0.000496939304005295, 0.003982653589719831, 0.0006493202563864209, 0.0028226535897197813]
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.13608
Точность расчета: 0.005502653589719575
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:04.110942
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.155989
0:00:00.601987
0:00:01.049980
0:00:01.495977
0:00:01.953979
0:00:02.394969
0:00:02.848960
0:00:03.290954
0:00:03.743949
0:00:04.110942
Массив отклонений: [0.03998265358971986, 0.006182653589719589, 0.00024932025638646493, 0.005582653589719655, 0.007982653589719835, 0.008849320256386406, 0.004668367875434232, 0.0038326535897197367, 0.0038493202563865125, 0.005502653589719575]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.15528
Точность расчета: 0.013697346410280087
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:04.167950
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.234007
0:00:00.686989
0:00:01.131984
0:00:01.584977
0:00:02.040978
0:00:02.483975
0:00:02.935971
0:00:03.382957
0:00:03.840950
0:00:04.167950
Массив отклонений: [0.03961734641028025, 0.03301734641028009, 0.020817346410280102, 0.01321734641028005, 0.012417346410280139, 0.007084013076946949, 0.010303060695994404, 0.01056734641028001, 0.01375067974361377, 0.013697346410280087]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.14988
Точность расчета: 0.008297346410280237
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:04.240946
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.339993
0:00:00.795983
0:00:01.241981
0:00:01.709975
0:00:02.160969
0:00:02.608969
0:00:03.062958
0:00:03.518952
0:00:03.973948
0:00:04.240946
Массив отклонений: [0.019182653589719934, 0.003217346410280264, 0.002150679743613715, 0.005417346410280022, 0.005457346410280284, 0.0024840130769470115, 0.007903060695994668, 0.008667346410280441, 0.008372901965835844, 0.008297346410280237]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.1364
Точность расчета: 0.005182653589719699
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:04.250946
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.269002
0:00:00.724986
0:00:01.173983
0:00:01.635973
0:00:02.093971
0:00:02.547963
0:00:03.005956
0:00:03.458952
0:00:03.918949
0:00:04.250946
Массив отклонений: [0.026382653589719585, 0.013582653589719662, 0.02144932025638635, 0.010982653589719948, 0.010142653589719774, 0.007049320256386604, 0.009468367875434147, 0.0059326535897197274, 0.007271542478608506, 0.005182653589719699]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Subprocess: 2.860181818181818
Точность расчета: 0.2814008354079016
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:07.784906
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.784988
0:00:01.529981
0:00:02.177976
0:00:02.897971
0:00:03.843958
0:00:04.740943
0:00:05.597933
0:00:06.397921
0:00:07.088914
0:00:07.784906
Массив отклонений: [0.016017346410280187, 0.005617346410280444, 0.007084013076946949, 0.011917346410280416, 0.010577346410280075, 0.00895067974361341, 0.008931632124566047, 0.005667346410280327, 0.004684013076946769, 0.00461734641028011]
Pi Subprocess: 2.8591636363636366
Точность расчета: 0.2824190172260832
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:07.805905
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.729991
0:00:01.601981
0:00:02.331970
0:00:03.236960
0:00:04.097951
0:00:04.847942
0:00:05.565931
0:00:06.269925
0:00:07.047914
0:00:07.805905
Массив отклонений: [0.005617346410280444, 0.012417346410280139, 0.015484013076946912, 0.015117346410280064, 0.012577346410280299, 0.006350679743613696, 0.0031602035531372863, 0.004267346410280037, 0.005084013076946725, 0.003497346410280322]
Pi Subprocess: 2.855090909090909
Точность расчета: 0.2864917444988109
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:08.172902
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.875990
0:00:01.735981
0:00:02.787969
0:00:03.645959
0:00:04.351950
0:00:05.211939
0:00:05.897928
0:00:06.698920
0:00:07.517913
0:00:08.172902
Массив отклонений: [0.016417346410280143, 0.008217346410280157, 0.004684013076946769, 0.0031826535897199193, 0.0002573464102804124, 0.005417346410280022, 0.005388774981708977, 0.0021673464102800466, 0.0015826535897196514, 0.0009826535897197175]
Pi Subprocess: 2.8591272727272727
Точность расчета: 0.28245538086244704
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:08.087902
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.742990
0:00:01.603978
0:00:02.334968
0:00:03.311956
0:00:04.085946
0:00:04.942939
0:00:05.864929
0:00:06.685921
0:00:07.597910
0:00:08.087902
Массив отклонений: [0.01041734641028036, 0.00461734641028011, 0.0018840130769470775, 0.005682653589719866, 0.0016973464102800762, 8.401307694683169e-05, 0.0015030606959944848, 0.002117346410280163, 0.0034840130769469013, 0.00345734641028006]
Pi Multiproc: 3.14688
Точность расчета: 0.005297346410280124
Время выполнения Multiproc:  0:00:27.403668
Промежуточное время:
0:00:13.526838
0:00:14.906877
0:00:16.519800
0:00:18.141782
0:00:19.758763
0:00:21.392813
0:00:23.025770
0:00:24.650722
0:00:26.286699
0:00:27.371742
Массив отклонений: [0.011182653589719926, 0.007982653589719835, 0.007182653589719923, 0.0011826535897196955, 0.0029426535897196793, 0.0009159869230530582, 0.00030306069599461694, 0.0020673464102802797, 0.005039568632502434, 0.005297346410280124]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Subprocess: 2.8563272727272726
Точность расчета: 0.28525538086244717
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:02.474973
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.252996
0:00:00.491002
0:00:00.732990
0:00:00.974989
0:00:01.242986
0:00:01.521994
0:00:01.766982
0:00:02.000979
0:00:02.242973
0:00:02.474973
Массив отклонений: [0.016017346410280187, 0.0019826535897196074, 0.003217346410280264, 0.0019826535897196074, 0.0017426535897198114, 0.0006493202563864209, 0.0011030606959945288, 0.0021673464102800466, 0.0017506797436137589, 0.00037734641028031035]
```

Кстати, чтобы получить этот вывод в файл на моей cp1252 консоли - это был отдельный квест!

Решилось добавлением такого кусочка в начало .py файла:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='cp1251', buffering=1)
```

### Дополнительно

Верните код в вопросе к первоначальному варианту - сейчас он совсем съехал.
Ваша проблема действительно в `if __name__ == '__main__':` Но только не там, где Вы думаете. Внутри кода он вообще не играет никакой роли.

А вот в конце он должен присутствовать:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    clas= PI()
    clas.LeibnicPI()
    clas.Thred()
    clas.Multiproc()
    clas.subproc()
```

Вот обновленный вывод:

```
Пи Лейбница: 3.1415826535897198
----------------------------------------------
Pi Thread: 3.13496
Точность расчета: 0.006622653589719807
Время выполнения Thread:  0:00:01.222235
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.061614
0:00:00.188699
0:00:00.318790
0:00:00.449798
0:00:00.580811
0:00:00.711381
0:00:00.838967
0:00:00.968986
0:00:01.099511
0:00:01.222235
Массив отклонений: [0.0035826535897198752, 0.010982653589719948, 0.0012173464102800402, 0.0014826535897198845, 0.0011373464102804043, 0.0071159869230532635, 0.007468367875433923, 0.011982653589719838, 0.009182653589719703, 0.006622653589719807]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Multiproc: 3.142
Точность расчета: 0.0004173464102801283
Время выполнения Multiproc:  0:00:03.026166
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.551109
0:00:00.823035
0:00:01.101084
0:00:01.373147
0:00:01.641457
0:00:01.916653
0:00:02.187227
0:00:02.463779
0:00:02.731894
0:00:03.004144
Массив отклонений: [0.005182653589719699, 0.004982653589719721, 0.01184932025638652, 0.015282653589719697, 0.011182653589719926, 0.005449320256386336, 0.002027504377565492, 0.0001826535897198056, 0.0003729019658358368, 0.0004173464102801283]
----------------------------------------------
Pi Subprocess: 2.856290909090909
Точность расчета: 0.28529174449881056
Время выполнения Subprocess:  0:00:03.260116
Промежуточное время:
0:00:00.321525
0:00:00.693528
0:00:00.986527
0:00:01.264030
0:00:01.613033
0:00:01.897607
0:00:02.223108
0:00:02.517611
0:00:02.939613
0:00:03.260116
Массив отклонений: [0.02398265358971985, 0.01078265358971997, 0.0006493202563864209, 0.0011173464102802733, 0.0011373464102804043, 0.0014493202563863328, 0.0027255107325769856, 0.001832653589719957, 0.0006048758119421294, 0.0003373464102800483]
```